# XSLT 2.0 - How to create a result using for each by selecting X number of nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to take a XML document with 40,000+ nodes and break the document into segments of 10,000 or less nodes.

For example XML where the item node repeats 40,000 plus times:

```
<catalog>
  <item>
    <partno>
    </partno>
  </item>
</catalog>
```

I'm trying to accomplish this structure where a new segment is created at each  10,000th item until the document is finished.

```
<segment>
  <Item></Item>(10,000 max)
</segment>
<segment>
  <Item></Item>(10,000 max)
</segment>
```

I'm sure I can do this with a modulus, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this in **XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:template match="catalog">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="(position() - 1) idiv 10000">
        <segment>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </segment>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Rupesh! This works perfectly and is much more elegant than how I was going to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `for-each-group group-by` I would suggest to use `group-adjacent` as that way if you move to XSLT 3 you can easily use streaming without changing the grouping code (you would simply need to set up the mode as `<xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>`):

```
<xsl:template match="catalog">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 10000">
    <xsl:result-document href="split{position()}.xml">
       <segment>
         <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
       </segment>
   </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```